# How do I view Annotations (i.e. pencil strokes) in the Sculpting Workspace?

Tags: sculpting, grease-pencil, workspaces, annotation

I am using the Annotate tool via <kbd>D</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> in the default Layout Workspace, and it works fine.

When I switch to the Sculpting Workspace, all the pencil strokes turn invisible! I can still draw, but they're just not there. How do I make them visible while in the sculpting workspace? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the *Viewport Overlays* options and enable *Annotations*. This will allow you to view the pencil strokes in the *Sculpting* workspace, where this option is disabled by default.

[image: Viewport Overlays]

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated! :)